# Indexing not working with column using range operations in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have created index on timestamp column for my table, but when I am querying and checking the explain plan in oracle it is doing the full table scan rather that range scan

Below is the DDL script for the table

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
   event_id     VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
   status       VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
   timestamp    NUMBER NOT NULL,
   action       VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE EVENT ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EVENT PRIMARY KEY ( event_id ) ;
CREATE INDEX IX_EVENT$timestamp ON EVENT (timestamp);
```

Below is the explain plan query used to get the explain plan -

```
EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = 'test3' for select * from EVENT where timestamp between 1620741600000 and 1621900800000 and status = 'CANC';

SELECT * FROM PLAN_TABLE WHERE STATEMENT_ID = 'test3';
```

Here is the explain plan that oracle returned -

[image]

I am not sure why the index is not working here, rather it is still doing the full table scan even after creating the index on the timestamp column.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Oracle has decided that the condition is not restrictive enough.  An index on `(status, timestamp)` would probably fare better.

Comment: How many rows are in the `event` table?  How many of them have a timestamp value in the range specified by your query (as an aside, `timestamp` is a reserved word so it's generally not a great idea to use that as a column name particularly when the data type is not `timestamp`)?  How many of them have a status of "CANC"?  How many have both the status you're looking for and are in the timestamp range?  What are Oracle's cardinality estimates?

Answer (score 0):

Gordon is correct. You need this index to speed up the query you showed us.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_EVENT$timestamp ON EVENT (status, timestamp);
```

Why? Your query requires an equality match on `status` and then a range scan on `timestamp`. Without the possibility of using the index for the equality match, Oracle's optimizer seems to have decided it's cheaper to scan the table than the index.

Why did it decide that?

Who knows? Hundreds of programmers have been working on the optimizer for many decades.

Who cares? Just use the right index for the query.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer is cost based. So conceptually the optimizer will evaluate all the available plans, estimate the cost, and pick the one that has the lowest estimated cost. The costs are estimated based on statistics. The index statistics are automatically collected when an index is built. However your table statistics may not reflect real life.
An Active SQL Monitor report will help you diagnose the issue.